# Restarting update manager after freezing!

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

While upgrading a distribution, the update manager freezes. How to restart the process of a safe upgrade?

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"? How do you know it is actually frozen?

Comment: I can't make out whether you are trying to help, given your language. 

However, here is the scenario. I can see a process named `saucy`. I can see that the upgrade window is dimmed and is not reacting to the mouse. My nautilus has crashed, and I cannot get it restarted again.

Comment: I was trying to help. Sorry for any confusion, however "freezes"  isn't the most descriptive word ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have taken the following steps to solve the condition:

```
sudo pkill saucy
```

This will kill the process named `saucy` which has frozen. Then there would be a need to reconfigure the downloaded packages. To do this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

There may be some packages which might have downloaded but not installed. To install them, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally, it might be possible that your system has actually not detected the upgrade (Well, strange things happen with computers!). Therefore to alleviate this problem run:

```
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

Comment: During an upgrade to 15.10 I found that I also had to `sudo pkill dpkg` a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the the process ID (PID) for the software updater by running: $ ps -aux | grep "Software Updater"
from the command line. Then shut it down by running: $ kill pid  and restart it.