# Upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 stops

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10, texlive

The upgrade to 13.10 stops after a lot of error messages about texlive packages, that I could close. The upgrade goes then further, but now it is stopped.

What can I do to initiate the process again?

[image: Upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 stops]

The following are the last messages from the command window.:

```
g multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 47: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 47: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 47: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 47: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 59: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 59: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 59: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 59: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 59: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 72: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 86: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 86: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 86: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 98: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 98: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 109: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 116: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 130: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 138: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 146: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 157: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 157: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 157: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 157: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 165: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 173: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 182: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf", line 182: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/99-language-selector-zh.conf", line 11: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
ERROR: error('unpack requires a bytes object of length 4',)

(apport-gtk:16828): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
```

Comment: As for the warnings themselves (if they appear again): [Fontconfig warning: “/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/485873/fontconfig-warning-etc-fonts-conf-d-90-fonts-unfonts-core-conf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in my case was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. After that, the Update-Manager began to clean up the system and all was working fine after the upgrade was finished.

Answer (score 0):

If your upgrade has stopped running: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then run `sudo apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the `saucy` update freezing, and I have put the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361506/restarting-update-manager-after-freezing/361703#361703). Incidentally Ramachandra Apte's solution is not complete.

[Restarting update manager after freezing!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361506/restarting-update-manager-after-freezing/361703#361703)