# upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 failed and broken dependencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I tried running the upgrade from my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 but it failed to upgrade a latex package with the error from [here] ([Upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 stops](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362389/upgrading-from-13-04-to-13-10-stops)) and calmed to try to roll back. However the computer clams to be on 13.10.

When I try to run `apt-get install` I get:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-chrono1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-date-time1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-filesystem1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-graph1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-iostreams1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-locale1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-math1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-mpi1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-program-options1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-python1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-random1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-regex1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-serialization1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-signals1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-system1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-test1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-thread1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-timer1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-wave1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and when I try `apt-get -f install` I get the error:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libboost1.49-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.49-doc xsltproc docbook-xsl fop
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libboost1.49-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
40 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,208 kB of archives.
After this operation, 36.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 598837 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libboost1.49-dev 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 (using .../libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libboost1.49-dev ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bcp', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_amd64
```

I considered removing a re-downloading boost but don't what to make my system any weirder and less stable.

Any suggestions on the best way to fix this problem and any other the failed upgrade might have made?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the `libboost1.49-dev` which was installed from an other repository is competing with newly installing `libboost1.49-dev` from main repository.

So first you need to remove the present `libboost1.49-dev`.

```
sudo dpkg --purge libboost1.49-dev
```

Then clean the apt-cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: How would you keep the old version if you wanted have both installed?

Comment: Did not work
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libboost1.49-dev:
 libboost-dev depends on libboost1.49-dev.

dpkg: error processing libboost1.49-dev (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libboost1.49-dev

Comment: I believe that many people have the same problem, there should be a solution

Comment: I also cannot remove the package with dpkg --purge