# Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf"

Tags: fonts

I am getting the following error frequently. (Example: when running `zenity`,`firefox` etc. commands / applications.)

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf", line 11: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
```

Here is contents of file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test name="family" qual="any">
            <string>은 바탕</string><string>UnBatang</string>
                <string>은 돋움</string><string>UnDotum</string>
                <string>은 궁서</string><string>UnGungseo</string>
                <string>은 필기</string><string>UnPilgi</string>
                <string>은 그래픽</string><string>UnGraphic</string>
        </test>

        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hinting"   mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>false</bool></edit>
        <edit name="autohint"  mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign" binding="strong"><const>hintslight</const></edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Well, look at it. It tells you quite specifically that there is a problem in line 11 of the file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf`. Apparently, you have multiple values in the `<test>` section. We might be able to be more specific if you post the relevant section.

Comment: post the output of `sed -n '11p' /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf`

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is `</test>`

Comment: @terdon I have added file But I don't know which multiple values? (I have not made any change in file manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I have not tested this!

This is a guess based on your error message. Since it is complaining that `<test></test>` sections can't have multiple values, probably all you need to do is split it into multiple ones:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test name="family" qual="any">
            <string>은 바탕</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
              <string>UnBatang</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
                <string>은 돋움</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
              <string>UnDotum</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
                <string>은 궁서</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
              <string>UnGungseo</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
                <string>은 필기</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
              <string>UnPilgi</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
                <string>은 그래픽</string>
        </test>
        <test name="family" qual="any">
              <string>UnGraphic</string>
        </test>

        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hinting"   mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>false</bool></edit>
        <edit name="autohint"  mode="assign" binding="strong"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign" binding="strong"><const>hintslight</const></edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: @Pandya no, you already have. The `foo -> bar` means that `foo` is a symlink to `bar`. That means that when you edit `foo` you are actually editing `bar`.

Comment: Ok. It is **solved** but Why This problem happened? is it bug?

Comment: @Pandya probably, or it is an older version of the file that was not changed when you upgraded or whatever. Don't really know, I've never seen it.